# Java Sorting Price Values Ascending and Descending

Tags: java

I have the price Values in String format ("2,000","3,000" etc)

I want to Sort the Price Values

for that I have used the Below Code:

```
Comparator<Cars> comparator = new Comparator<Cars>() {

          @Override
          public int compare(Cars object1, Cars object2) {
          // return Float.compare(Integer.parseInt(object1.getPrice()), Integer.parseInt(object2.getPrice()));

           return ((Integer)Integer.parseInt(object1.getPrice())).compareTo((Integer)Integer.parseInt( object2.getPrice())); 

          }
```

If i execute the Below Statement

```
        Collections.sort(carsList, comparator);
```

I'm getting

```
Error:  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3,000"
```

Could any one help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt()` will not work with currency containing commas(`,`). You may have to do the string manipulation to remove the comma before trying to use the `parseInt()` method.

Doing something like this:

```
String obj1Price = object1.getPrice().replaceAll(",","");
String obj2Price = object2.getPrice().replaceAll(",","");

return ((Integer)Integer.parseInt(obj1Price )).compareTo((Integer)Integer.parseInt( obj2Price)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer,I will accept your answer,But i have one more query ,if i have a "-" value as Price then how sort will work?

Comment: @IceCreamSandwitch If have "-" then also u need to replace them with "" to make parseInt to work.

Comment: I have replaced "-" with "" ,then getting Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" ?

Comment: @IceCreamSandwitch What is the final stirng you get before you are trying to use parsetInt()?

Comment: if i call a getter method to get price  then the value is  "-"?

Comment: @IceCreamSandwitch Simply do this then : object1.getPrice().replaceAll("-","");

Comment: I have done this : String price1=object1.getPrice().replaceAll(",","");
            price1=price1.replaceAll("-","");

Comment: But getting the Exception ,my String price value is like this 3,000,2,000,300,- etc....

Comment: The Exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35412/discussion-between-icecream-sandwitch-and-juned-ahsan)

Answer (score 2):

Modify the currency data(the String representation) before passing it to your method, e.g. you can use this:

```
"2,000".replaceAll(",","");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt("3,000")
```

is throwing the exception. You need to get rid off `,` from the string representation of your price.

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {

              @Override
              public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                  int i = 0;
                int j = 0;
                try {
                    i = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse(object1).intValue();
                      j = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse(object2).intValue();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
              // return Float.compare(Integer.parseInt(object1.getPrice()), Integer.parseInt(object2.getPrice()));
                    System.out.println("i = " + ((Integer)i) + " , j = " + ((Integer)j));

               return ((Integer)i).compareTo(((Integer)j)); 

              } 
          };
            System.out.println("xxxxxxxxx = " + comparator.compare("4,000", "3,000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ((Integer)Integer.parseInt(obj1Price.replaceAll(",","") )).compareTo((Integer)Integer.parseInt( obj2Price.replaceAll(",",""))));
```

Will work